# Tell `ls` to sort by regular ASCII codes, not "intelligently"

Tags: ls, file-sorting

I have a couple files and `ls` sorts them like this:

```
a
_b
c
```

but I want to have

```
_b
a
c
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Might I ask why?

Comment: I use the underscore to denote special directories that need to go to top. In my projects folder, I have proj_a, proj_b and _old_projects. It is no use if this folder is within the o-projects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a one-off command you can do this:

`LC_COLLATE=C ls`

Or you can add `export LC_COLLATE="C"` to your .bashrc to make it permanent (may have unexpected results sorting elsewhere).

More information on [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=816753).

Comment: I guess I will just alias ls with that, so that it does not have side effects.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get this -> http://paste.pocoo.org/show/403333/ (it's german but it shouldn't matter)

Comment: @dAnjou `LC_COLLATE=C` ls sets the traditional POSIX sorting order, which is by ASCII in which uppercase comes before underscore. To have underscores sort before uppercase you'd have to get under the bonnet and create a custom locale definition under /usr/share/i18n/locales.

Comment: This may have worked in the past, but it's not working on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 14.04, `LC_COLLATE=C ls` does not work, but `LC_ALL=C ls` does.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case there isn't a built-in way to do this, you could use a simple replacement  for `sort`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for i in sorted(sys.stdin):
    sys.stdout.write(i)
```

Save it, for example, at `/bin/pysort` and make it executable (`sudo cp whatever.py /bin/pysort` and `sudo chmod a+x /bin/pysort`), and run it as `ls | pysort`:

```
stefano@lenovo:~/t$ ls | pysort
_b
a
c
```

Comment: I would probably put it in `~/bin` but nice fallback. It is probably better to use globbing within python since the output of ls might be strange if a filename contains a newline.

Answer (score 1):

would `ls | sort` not do exactly what you need?

Comment: no, that sorts it as "a _b c"

Comment: no! and sort also has not got an option for this :-)

Comment: It is strange that sort has so many special sorting ways but not the "use ASCII value" one …

Answer (score 1):

As of 2024, the `LC_COLLATE=C ls` option works perfectly for me on Ubuntu 22.04 with sort (GNU coreutils) 8.32 and `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`. However, in case this does not work on your platform/locale, you could do this fairly easily with perl:

```
ls | perl -e '@f=sort <>; print @f'
```

I was also surprised that I couldn't find a relevant option in the `sort` man page.