# SORT: Why is it different in open/save window then elsewhere?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, locale, thunar, sort

The sort order in my Xubuntu file manager (Thunar) is the way I want it, with types of characters in the following order:

> - non alphanumeric (principally: underscore, hyphen, dot)
> - numerics
> - alphabetics (lowercase, uppercase, and accented characters treated as equal)

When I OPEN an existing file or "SAVE AS" a file in any program, the file/directory listing window puts all of the uppercase characters together,
before the lowercase ones.  Now with the research I have done I know that the unwanted (by me) lower/uppercase treatment is due to LC_COLLATE=C.  I chose 'C' because of the separation it gives between alphanumerics and the other characters, but I don't want lower/uppercase to be separated.

What I don't know is 1) how come this lower/uppercase treatment does not happen in my regular Thunar display, 2) why there is this discrepancy between the OPEN/SAVE behavior and the regular Thunar.

Here is my "locale" output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I'm on Xubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Thank you.

Comment: Because those dialogues are iimplemented by each program individually, not through file browser.

Comment: Ok Serg, this answers 2) but what about 1) how come Thunar does not segregate upper/lowercase characters like setting LC_COLLATE=C should do?  (Ironically I prefer the way it is now, but I'd like to understand.)  Also, aren't there ways that installed programs typically make use of OS settings/parameters?  The "locale" values affect more than just the file manager.

Comment: As you seem to have figured out, the sort order in some (most?) programs is determined by the locale stated for `LC_COLLATE`. Probably Thunar has defined its own sort order. Possibly some of all the available locales fit your specification, but don't ask me which locales do. ;)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson according to this comment, `LC_COLLATE` doesn't "work" in Ubuntu 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47702/tell-ls-to-sort-by-regular-ascii-codes-not-intelligently/47716#comment792974_47716

Comment: Hadn't heard, and can't reproduce (on 15.10). Wonder what the source of that is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well nothing new since Gunnar Hjalmarsson posted on March 14.

The answer has two parts:

1) when open/save with a program, the program itself chooses how it sorts the files shown, potentially ignoring the user's choice of sort type

2) LC_COLLATE is somehow broken in Ubuntu 14.04.

I, the original poster, did not really answer anything.  I just want closure.  1) was answered by @Serg  2) was answered by @Gunnar

For those who know more than me, please make the appropriate edits and give whatever points where they belong.  Thank you.